# Blender - Export to DAE with texture

Tags: textures, blender, texture-mapping, 3d-model

Okay, i have a really wierd problem. I am totally new to blender, and i have just bought a 3D model of a present, to play a little around with.

The 3D model looks very nice, and in Rendered, Material and texture mode are all the materials showing perfectly fine (not in Solid though, the present is just gray here).

So... Now i want to make this file into a .dae-file, so that i can use it in Xcode. And here comes the problem. "The model export, but not the texture." And i dont want a totally gray present in my app. ;)

I have nothing done with the present (nothing else than pay $ for it). I go into: Export -> Collada (.dae) and have the Texture options like this:

[image]

(I have also tried the other options)

[image]

The blender file looks like this in blender.

[image]
But the .dae-file look like this.

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Most (if not all) 3d file formats do not transport textures with them, only geometry information and uvmaps which describe how to apply textures, but no color information. What you should do is export textures from blender and then import dae file and textures into your target application separately. Then apply the material/texture onto object inside that application. 
This might help you:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/106132/54801

Comment: Sorry, but this is not correct: DAE and even old OBJ support textures, so it is actually specifically a Blender application problem for some reason - I am on Blender v3.6.4 and it sucks a lot in this regard, really.

Comment: @fafa according to specification OBJ carries over geometry (verticies and normals) and texture coordinates, not textures themselves. You can have MTL file that specifies texture names, but again not textures themselves. 
https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000507.shtml